# Qt and GLEW: The program exited with code -1073741515

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glew

I an working with Qt and I am trying to switch from OpenGL 1.0 to a newer OpenGL by using GLEW. 
I have a GUi which uses a subclass of QGLWidget to process OpenGL stuff. At the beginning of `initializeGL` I do the statement `GLenum err = glewInit();` and this causes the following:

```
program.exe exited with code -1073741515
```

Some more details:
libs:

```
LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v1.7/lib/amd64/" -lKinect10
LIBS += -lOpenGL32
LIBS += -lglew32
LIBS += -lglu32
```

Headers:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
```

Full initializeGL() function:

```
void OpenGLWidget::initializeGL(){
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
      /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */

    }
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Enables the drawing of 2D textures
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width(), height(), 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) NULL);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId); //Binds the GL_TEXTURE_2D to the textureId
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width(), height(), 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) blackScreen); //Strart the program off with a black screen
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId); //Binds the GL_TEXTURE_2D to the textureId
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is generally a pain to get GLEW to play w/ Qt. Qt provides a method to get the GL functions after you initialize the context. If you're targeting 4.3, it would be: QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core *funcs = context->versionFunctions(); -- note that there has been some significant changes in Qt 5.1; all for the best though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Does your version of Qt come with OpenGL support? Believe it or not, some don't. This was the case for me and it drove me crazy. Download a version of Qt with OpenGL support and replace the one you have. If all goes well you shouldn't have a problem.
- If you don't want to download a prebaked version, you must build Qt from scratch. This requires Python, Perl, possibly Ruby, and more than a little patience (because it's never as easy as the tutorials make you think).
- The error code you're getting seems to be a [linking error](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26213-exited-with-code-1073741511) that seems to have been solved [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26604-Runtime-problem-in-Release-mode/page2). Hopefully that solves it.

Comment: I have compiled this version of Qt 4.8.4 myself and it has OpenGL support. The program was running fine using OpenGL, but I used very outdated stuff. I amt rying to use newer stuff and I want to do that rough GLEW. Which brings me to this problem.

Comment: It was indeed the Glew DLL not being on the PATH. Thank you =)